# NLP - Finding parenthetical sentence

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I need help to find parenthetical information in a sentence.

E.g.,

1. Some foods, **sugar for example**, are not good for us.
2. Timothy, **who lives near Stonehenge**, goes to church regularly.
   Are there any libraries in NLP to find parenthetical information in a sentence?
   Chunking, Co-reference resolution, Dependency parser in NLP will not give efficient results in finding parenthetical sentences. And we cannot go by the pattern alone. 
   E.g.,
3. commas , .......,
4. round brackets (.......)
5. long dashes —.......—

There are so many exceptions to the above patterns.

Comment: What are the “so many exceptions”? Please edit some examples of these many exceptions into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Given a training set where parenthetical sentences follow a pattern that could be captured using a regex, you could train you own sequence tagging model that extract such sentences depending on the semantics, even if they follow no particular pattern using the original sentences as training data after removing any commas/parentheses etc.